# Radial path of body released from uniform circular motion?

Tags: reference-frames, rotation

A body is undergoing uniform circular motion. Imagine a mass swung in a circle on a string in the absence of gravity or the motion of the Earth about the sun. At some point, the string is cut or, in the other example, gravity is instantaneously turned off.

Is there any *reasonable* frame of reference that depicts the body moving radially away from the center of rotation?

[This question is prompted by an overly extensive comment section in another question. I feel obliged to bring it here since it seems to need more elaboration than comments provide.]

Edit: I'm considering deleting this question. As mentioned, it was intended to bring an ancillary discussion from the comments of another question her where they could be more fully discussed. The person(s) involved there seem not interested in participating. Missing the context there, the question here, in isolation, seems rather deflated of meaning.

Comment: I was hoping the person arguing yes, or one of  his/her supporters, would make an appearance here.

Comment: An inertial frame will do it approximately if you wait until its distance from the center of rotation is much greater than the original radius.

Comment: @garyp Agreed. Emphasis on "approximately" and "large distance".

Answer (score 0):

I say no.
The top figure in the diagram below shows how the scenario would appear to a stationary observer above. In this non-inertial frame, the body (red circle) moves off on a tangent to the circle.

Case A takes on the frame of reference of an observer looking down the radius at the moment the body is released. This rotating frame of reference swings around with the circle and does not even keep the body in sight. True, the observer could rotate herself to keep the body in sight. But what an inordinately complicated and useless frame of reference this would be. The user would have to rotate in a non-uniform manner. This would not even be a dreaded accelerated frame of reference, it would be a jerk frame of reference. (Jerk meaning non-uniform acceleration for the neophytes here.)

Case B is from the body’s frame of reference, kept stationary with respect to the body. Orient it any way you wish, but keep it stationary relative to the body, and it will only look down a radius at one moment in its path.

Case C allows the observer moving with the body to turn his head to constantly look down a radius. There’s that jerk again. The rotation, therefore acceleration, of the observer is again non-uniform and unreasonable. Furthermore, the observer isn’t even looking down the same radius.
[image]

Comment: I agree with your conclusion, but I can't understand your diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by "moving radially". 
In the reference frame attached to the center of rotation, the velocity will have a radial component. Only at the moment when the string is cut the velocity have to radial component. At any moment after that the radial component is non-zero.
So it has a radial component of the motion.

It looks like you are making up your own definitions just to force the answer to be "no". The motion is linear, yes. And any linear motion is purely radial in a polar coordinate system with the origin on the line. There is no angular component in displacement or velocity so it is purely radial. The fact that the  motion was circular at some prior time is completely irrelevant. Ant linear motion can have an angular component if the origin of the coordinates is not on the trajectory.  Of course, it is not radial if the origin is in the center of the original circle. But you asked if there is ANY coordinate system.  And there are many.

Comment: Entirely along a radius, from some frame of reference, not just a component.

Comment: From any reference frame with the origin on the linear trajectory, the motion is purely radial, isn't it?

Comment: That would be linear. Sure, it "radiates out" along a line from its point of release. But, since we are looking at circular motion, "radially" implies along a radius of the circle.  As you imply in your answer, the path approaches a radial retreat as it gets very far away (as per @garyp comment to the question). That is, at very far distances it closely appears to be receding directly away from the rotational center. But the point of the question is whether there is a valid frame of reference from which all of the body's motion, once released, is along a radius of the circle.

Comment: It looks like you are making up your own definitions just to force the answer to be "no".

Comment: Completely unfair. To say that a component of the bodies motion is radial does not qualify as a "radial path", note the title of my question. All bodies moving relative to one another have a "radial component" excepting the one potential instance where the motion may be tangential.

Comment: I don't se what is unfair. I did not mean just one component to to be radial. If the origin is on the straight line trajectory, the motion is fully radial. It is a quite trivial matter, I don't see any reason to make a big deal out of it. Any linear motion can be described as radial in polar coordinates. And any purely radial motion is linear. What else is to it?

Comment: Sorry. I did not see that you had edited your answer, adding the second paragraph.  Of course, place a rotational coordinate system, that doesn't rotate, at the point of release and you could describe the motion as radial.

Answer (score 0):

It would move radially out on a rotating coordinate system with its angle of rotation $\theta = arctan(  \omega)$
With $\omega$ being the rotation just before the release.

Comment: Would "case C" in my answer depict your coordinate system in action? That is, does your equation describe the line connecting the body to the circle's center? If not, I'm having trouble picturing it.

Comment: I did nor read your answer, but a quick inspection would indicate yes. I will look at it when I get back home.